# Drupal 7 - Theme Info Name Errors After Transferring Site to New Server

Tags: database, drupal, themes, title, transfer

After transferring over a finished site to a new server, files/database and all, switching over the database settings in `settings.php` and running `update.php` I get the following errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: name in block_menu() (line 146 of /home/nrsc2533/public_html/modules/block/block.module).
Notice: Undefined index: name in block_menu() (line 165 of /home/nrsc2533/public_html/modules/block/block.module).
Notice: Undefined index: name in system_menu() (line 647 of /home/nrsc2533/public_html/modules/system/system.module).
Notice: Undefined index: name in block_menu() (line 146 of /home/nrsc2533/public_html/modules/block/block.module).
Notice: Undefined index: name in block_menu() (line 165 of /home/nrsc2533/public_html/modules/block/block.module).
Notice: Undefined index: name in system_menu() (line 647 of /home/nrsc2533/public_html/modules/system/system.module).
```

I also lose most if not all of the items in the admin menu. I looked up the errors and they were all related to the following line of code:

```
'title' => check_plain($theme->info['name']),
```

This is a free theme that I customized, it is working fine on my test domain on my server, but not now that it has transferred. I did change the [theme].info file to reflect that it had been customized on the "name =" line. I checked online and found that the encoding may have been changed when I saved it, again strange since I had done this on the test domain and it seemed fine, so I changed the encoding to UTF-* without BOM and still to no avail. I have tried clearing the cache again via update.php and nothing changes. Any help will be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: I also should add that other errors randomly pop in regarding the same $theme->info['name'] in other modules

Comment: try to set different theme and again change to your theme, may be sometimes it will resolve!!

Comment: Already tried that and no dice, same errors

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall the theme, if you still get the error then check the theme bug report or submit the bug.

Comment: Still not working and it is a custom theme? Really strange considering that it works fine on my subdomain and the only thing I have changed was the database location(yes I updated settings.php)